# krakenjs and node postgres

Tags: node.js, node-postgres, kraken.js

How do I set up node-postgres using krakenjs? I want to take advantage of node-postgres's connection pooling which requires the `client` and `done` parameters. I guess I could set them using global variables, but I'd rather pass them around as an object. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to take advantage of node-postgres connection pooling, without having to mess with `client` / `done` methods, have a look at [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the pool in `onconfig` in the kraken (1.0) configuration, or in global based on `nconf` (kraken 0.7).

Then to pass it around -- you can attach it to the app (kraken 0.7), or you can add it to the configuration in `onconfig`.